# How to use ObservableList in a Constructor

Tags: constructor, javafx, observablelist

i have a little question for Java-Fx and Observable-lists. I want to build a Timetable for a couple of persons. There for i have a Person-Class, in which i want to give every Person its own Observable-list in the Constructor. Someone got a notation for this case? i have already tried so stuff but nothing seems to work. On one hand i need an Attribute for the List to build a getter-Method for it and i want to give each Person its own List.

this is my Attribut:

ObservableList personTableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

now i need the notation for the Constructor!

thanks, Manuel

Comment: Do you want to add data into the list inside the constructor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you exactly what you want to gain.
E.g.:

```
public class Person {

   private ObservableList personTableList;

   public Person() {
      this(null);
   }

   public Person(ObservableList list) {
      if (list == null) {
         this.personTableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
      } else {
         this.personTableList = list;
      }

   }

   public ObservableList getPersonTableList() {
      return this.personTableList;
   } 

   public void setPersonTableList(ObservableList list) {
      this.personTableList = list;
   }
}
```

Using e.g.:

```
new Person();
```

Comment: Ah ok, my Problem is more, that i want to give each Person its own ObservableList automatically. You know like the initialization of an ArrayList or so in the Constructor, without giving it in the Constructor-Head.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if it is sufficient for you.

Comment: Well the solution is perfect, I think I have a communication problem here, the class above Person, has a default constructor calling the 'sub' constructor.. so the new person doesn't need to put a new observable list, every class that extends person does'nt need to create its own observable list.